# Emacs: load-file .emacs when saved

Tags: emacs, buffer, hook

I'm new to emacs and lisp.

I wanted to auto-load the dot file when it was saved. Meaning, when I save my .emacs file, it would automatically call `load-file` on it (thus letting me know right away if I messed up).

But I can't seen to be able to find a comprehensive tutorial on hooks in emacs.

This is what I've come up with:

```
(defun load-init-after-save ()
  "After saving this file, load it"
  (if (eq bname this) ('load-file this) (nil))
)
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'load-init-after-save)
```

Of course, this is incorrect: `bname` and `this` are just placeholders. And I don't want this function to run on all saves, just when the `.emacs` file is saved.

Does anyone know how to do this? Is there a better, easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code loads your `.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file after save:

```
(defun my-load-user-init-file-after-save ()
  (when (string= (file-truename user-init-file)
                 (file-truename (buffer-file-name)))
    (let ((debug-on-error t))
      (load (buffer-file-name)))))

(add-hook 'after-save-hook #'my-load-user-init-file-after-save)
```

Since your intended use is error-checking, the code also enables the debugger while loading the init file, so that you get a nice backtrace in case of errors.

For error checking of your init file you may also find [Flycheck](http://flycheck.org) useful.  It checks your init file on the fly with the byte compiler, highlights any errors and warnings in the buffer, and—optionally—gives you a list of all errors and warnings.

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of this library.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I needed. Thanks! I'll also take a look at your Flycheck.

Comment: @Nacht You are welcome.  If you try Flycheck, I'd love to hear some feedback about it.  In particular, I'd like to hear if the setup instructions were helpful, and how well you succeeded in getting it up and running.

Answer (score 2):

### Way 1

One way of doing is to install `auto-compile-mode` from MELPA, and enable it:

```
(defun my-emacs-lisp-hook ()
  (auto-compile-mode 1))

(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'my-emacs-lisp-hook)
```

Now each time you save an Elisp file that's byte-compiled, it will be
re-compiled. Compilation will usually catch some bad errors.

To compile any Elisp file, select it in `dired` (<kbd>C-x d</kbd>)
and press <kbd>B</kbd> (`dired-do-byte-compile`).

### Way 2

Use this custom code I wrote.

```
(defun test-emacs ()
  (interactive)
  (require 'async)
  (async-start
   (lambda () (shell-command-to-string "emacs --batch --eval \"(condition-case e (progn (load \\\"~/.emacs\\\") (message \\\"-OK-\\\")) (error (message \\\"ERROR!\\\") (signal (car e) (cdr e))))\""))
   `(lambda (output)
      (if (string-match "-OK-" output)
          (when ,(called-interactively-p 'any)
            (message "All is well"))
        (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*startup error*")
        (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
        (insert output)
        (search-backward "ERROR!")))))

(defun auto-test-emacs ()
  (when (eq major-mode 'emacs-lisp-mode))
  (test-emacs))

(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'auto-test-emacs)
```

This will start a new Emacs instance in the background each time you
save a file. If something goes wrong, it will complain.
The second approach uses [async](https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-async).

If you really want to do this *just* for `.emacs` user this:

```
(defun auto-test-emacs ()
  (when (and (eq major-mode 'emacs-lisp-mode)
             (equal (file-truename user-init-file)
                    (expand-file-name
                     buffer-file-truename)))
    (test-emacs)))
```

Comment: Yes, [`auto-compile`](https://github.com/tarsius/auto-compile) is excellent. I *thoroughly* recommend using it.

Comment: abo-abo: You should link to `async`.

Comment: It sounds like this will auto-compile any lisp file I save. I want to just recompile the `.emacs` file when it (and only it) is saved. This will work at the moment (since I'm not modifying any other lisp files) but eventually it won't be good.